# Не могу заавтовайрить PasswordHasherInterface

Tags: php, symfony, хеширование, framework, service

Всем привет. Пилю маленький проект на новой Symfony 6.1
Подключил фикстуры и появилась необходимость захешировать пароль. Покопался в доках, нашёл PasswordHasherInterface

```
<?php
namespace App\DataFixtures;

use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Email;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Id;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\Role;
use App\Model\User\Entity\User\User;
use Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\Fixture;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\PasswordHasherInterface;

class UserFixture extends Fixture
{
    private PasswordHasherInterface $hasher;

    public function __construct(PasswordHasherInterface $hasher)
    {
        $this->hasher = $hasher;
    }
    
    public function load(ObjectManager $manager): void
    {
        $hash = $this->hasher->hash("password");

        $user = User::signUpByEmail(
            Id::next(),
            new \DateTimeImmutable(),
            new Email("admin@app.test"),
            $hash,
            "token"
        );

        $user->confirmSignUp();

        $user->changeRole(Role::admin());

        $manager->persist($user);
        $manager->flush();
    }
}
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
In DefinitionErrorExceptionPass.php line 54:
!!                                                                                 
!!    Cannot autowire service "App\DataFixtures\UserFixture": argument "$hasher"   
!!    of method "__construct()" references interface "Symfony\Component\PasswordH  
!!    asher\PasswordHasherInterface" but no such service exists. Did you create a  
!!    class that implements this interface?                                       
!!
```

Мой файл services.yaml:

```
parameters:

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Model/User/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
```

Как захешировать пароль в Symfony 6.1?

Comment: а просто встроенные функции пхп использовать нельзя? в чем прелесть внедрения зависимостей и сторонних классов для реализации функций которые на уровне языка поддерживаются и так?

Comment: А в security.yaml что?

Comment: К тому же в доке описывается внедрение UserPasswordHasherInterface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интерфейс `PasswordHasherInterface` имплиментирован нескольким хешерам. Автовайринг не сможет выбрать подходящий. Придется указать руками в services.yml

```
App\DataFixtures\UserFixture:
    arguments:
        Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\NativePasswordHasher
```

Либо сконфигурить хешер для всего приложения (https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/passwords.html#configuring-a-password-hasher) и доставать его через фабрику, которая будет инъектиться в Ваш сервис

Comment: А как указать руками в services.yml ?
Указал в security.yaml
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'bcrypt'
        App\Model\User\Entity\User\User: 'bcrypt'
        Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\PasswordHasherInterface: 'bcrypt'

Comment: Но ошибка осталась... Как указать правильно?

Comment: Добавил в ответ пример конфига. NativePasswordHasher в аргументах для примера, выберете свой хешер.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Разве что нужно добавить тире

 - Symfony\Component\PasswordHasher\Hasher\NativePasswordHasher